# How to properly configure Context path and docBase in Tomcat under MacOS?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, server

I am new to Tomcat and am trying to configure the  in server.xml to access a local html webapp in a Mac environment. This is what I did:

**1. HTML webapp: index.html**

The path is /Users/username/Desktop/index.html. This HTML has been tested so it is not wrong.

**2. Configure the server.xml file in CATALINA_HOME directory**

I added an additional Host in the server.xml and configured the Context as follow:

```html
<Host name="www.test.com" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"> 

  <Context path="/testDir" docBase="/Users/username/Desktop" reloadable="true" caseSensitive="false" debug="0"/>
  
</Host>
```

**3. Add IP in HOST file**

I went to the HOST file and added the new hostname as "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx www.test.com"

**4. Restart Tomcat and try to access**

I was able to access [www.test.com:8888](http://www.test.com:8888) which is the homepage. However, as I went to [www.test.com:8888/testDir/index.html](http://www.test.com:8888/testDir/index.html), the page kept loading and show no content.

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: _"the page kept loading and show no content"_ - which one is it: does the server never return a response or does it return an empty content (test with `curl`)? I assume you reconfigured Tomcat to listen on port `8888`? The default configuration listens on port `8080`.

Comment: It never returned any response and when the page stopped loading, an empty page is shown(I can't inspect its content elements). And yes I did changed the port to 8888.